# How can I fix a vagrant machine that is corrupting after a certain amount of time?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, vagrant

I am new to vagrant virtual machines. I set up a vagrant machine with 2 nodes for Kubernetes. 1 master and 1 node.

Everything is being ok but after a certain amount of time the cluster crashes and when I try to access to vagrant master machine is everything super slow and showing messages like this when I try to access kubectl status:

```
Failed to get properties: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
```

I have already tried to increase VM RAM and disk size, but I don't have clue where it should be failing.